# I have added an OnPaint() function to my dialog class but its not getting called after dlg.DoModal()

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, modal-dialog, onpaint

Can anyone please help me understand how to override `OnPaint()` for a dialog class derived from `CDialog`.

Here is the code:

```
ColorImageDlg *pDlg = NULL;
pDlg = new ColorImageDlg;
pDlg->DoModal();
delete pDlg;
```

I'm overriding `OnInitDialog()` and it's getting called.
But while overriding `OnPaint()` it is not getting called.

Can any one please help me fixing it?

Comment: I got the answer its adding  ON_WM_PAINT() as below. Now its executing onpaint();
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ColorImageDlg, CDialog)
 ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP().

Thank you.

Comment: What is the point of creating the instance of the dialog on heap? You can simply do: `ColorImageDlg dlg;
dlg.DoModal();`

Comment: Create your handlers through the class wizard. It creates all needed code.

Comment: `OnPaint` is not virtual function. You need to put `ON_WM_PAINT` in message map entry. Browse to its definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all what is the point of creating the instance of the dialog on heap? You can simply do:

```
ColorImageDlg dlg;
dlg.DoModal();
```

You need to modify your message map like this:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ColorImageDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Use **VS Class Wizard** to avoid problems like that.

Comment: There is no Class Wizard in Visual Studio 2008. It re-surfaced as late as Visual Studio 2010, and has been included in Visual Studio ever since (currently up to VS 2015).

Comment: Class wizard existed since VC6 (even before). They hid the "ClassWizard" term, but message handling continued to work. VS2010 has revamped it.

Comment: @Ajay: The Class Wizard was removed with Visual Studio 2002, and re-introduced with Visual Studio 2010. It wasn't hidden, it was completely removed. I have no idea, how the class wizard and message handling are related. They are completely separate entities.

Comment: @IInspectable, It was there for dialog/menu editor to have "Add Event..." or on double clicking a button/menu/checkbox etc. Not ClassWizard, but basic wizard. I am not sure if `WM_PAINT` could have been handled.

Comment: Yes! If you click the class name on left,  then right click and select add event handler.  Choose wm_paint.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use the **ClassWizard** then there is another way. Here is a resource about it:

(**VS2015** version) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dey7ke4c.aspx

(**VS2008** version) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dey7ke4c(v=vs.90).aspx)

But basically, once you have defined the **dialog resource** and **attached** it to a **new class**, make sure the **Class View** tab is selected:

[image: Class View]

Next, make sure your dialog class is **selected** in the class view:

[image: Class]

Then, click on the Messages icon of the **Properties** panel:

[image: Messages]

Scroll down the list of messages and locate `WM_PAINT`. Then click the dropdown arrow and select the option to add it:

[image: WM_PAINT]

As you can see, it has inserted all the needed code:

[image: New Code]

Hope this helps.